# simplity construction of sparse (transition) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix, simplify

I am constructing a transition matrix from a `n1 x n2 x ... x nN x nN` array. For concreteness let `N = 3`, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np

# example with N = 3
n1, n2, n3 = 3, 2, 5
dim = (n1, n2, n3)
arr = np.random.random_sample(dim + (n3,))
```

Here `arr` contains transition probabilities between 2 states, where the "from"-state is indexed by the first 3 dimensions, and the "to"-state is indexed by the first 2 and the last dimension. I want to construct a transition matrix, which expresses these probabilities raveled into a sparse `(n1*n2*n3) x (n1*n2*n3` matrix.

To clarify, let me provide my current approach that does what I want to do. Unfortunately, it's slow and doesn't work when `N` and `n1, n2, ...` are large. So I am looking for a more efficient way of doing the same that scales better for larger problems.

#### My approach

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse as sparse

## step 1: get the index correponding to each dimension of the from and to state

# ravel axes 1 to 3 into single axis and make sparse 
spmat = sparse.coo_matrix(arr.reshape(np.prod(dim), -1))
data = spmat.data
row = spmat.row
col = spmat.col

# use unravel to get idx for 
row_unravel = np.array(np.unravel_index(row, dim))
col_unravel = np.array(np.unravel_index(col, n3))

## step 2: combine "to" index with rows 1 and 2 of "from"-index to get "to"-coordinates in full state space

row_unravel[-1, :] = col_unravel # first 2 dimensions of state do not change
colnew = np.ravel_multi_index(row_unravel, dim) # ravel back to 1d

## step 3: assemble transition matrix

out = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, colnew)), shape=(np.prod(dim), np.prod(dim)))
```

#### Final thought

I will be running this code many times. Across iterations, the data of `arr` may change, but the dimensions will stay the same. So one thing I could do is to save and load `row` and `colnew` from a file, skipping everything between the definition of `data` (line 2) and final line of my code. Do you think this would be the best approach?

Edit: One problem I see with this strategy is that if some elements of `arr` are zero (which is possible) then the size of `data` will change across iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that beats the one posted in the OP. Not sure if it's the most efficient.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

# get col and row indices
idx = np.arange(np.prod(dim))
row = idx.repeat(dim[-1])
col = idx.reshape(-1, dim[-1]).repeat(dim[-1], axis=0).ravel()

# get the data
data = arr.ravel()

# construct the sparse matrix
out = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(np.prod(dim), np.prod(dim)))
```

Two things that could be improved:

(1) if `arr` is sparse, the output matrix `out` will have zeros coded as nonzero.

(2) The approach relies on the new state being the last dimension of `dim`. It would be nice to generalize so that the last axis of `arr` can replace any of the originating axis, not just the last one.